# How can I fake Assembly.LoadFile and Assembly.GetTypes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes

I'm struggling to fake these two lines of code:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);
Type[] asmTypes = loggerAssembly.GetTypes();
```

When I type `System.Reflection.ShimAssembly` there is no such type as `ShimAssembly` like for example in the case of `System.IO.ShimFile` but only a `StubAssembly`.

I could refactor the code and do it with a static helper method like `LoadAssemblyAndGetTypes` but it seems to be an unnecessary workaround. I'd prefer the *official* solution.

If it only worked like this:

```
var shimAsm = System.Reflection.Fakes.ShimAssembly.LoadFile = (fileName) => 
{ 
   return ???
}; 

var types = shimAsm.GetTypes = () => 
{ 
   return new Type[] { new object() };
};
```

Why does it work for `System.IO.File` and not for `System.Reflection.Assembly`. Is this because `Assembly` is an abstract class?

---

In my unit test I want to check if my assembly loader correctly checks if the loaded assembly contains types that implement some interfaces so that I can instantiate them later later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer and it doesn't look good:

@Patrick Tseng - Visual Studio team - writes at [Shim mscorlib and system limitations](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74fd087e-d833-4254-85be-8e1c1b0c5b61/shim-mscorlib-and-system-limitations?forum=vsunittest):

> ...we DO have a list of type we purposely not allowing them to be
>   shimmed. Reason being that it could potentially cause recurisvely
>   calling into your detour delegate from CLR runtime itself.  E.g If CLR
>   runtime uses a type in System.Reflection during runtime and you happen
>   to detour functions in this type. You might end up causing expected
>   behavior since runtime behavior will totally be changed.
>
> In short, we don't shim value type, System.Reflection.*,
>   System.Runtime.*, XamlGeneratedNamespace,  and a few other types which
>   we deem is important and will not shim them.

so after all it seems I'll need to keep the static helper method.